# Bookmark page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

window.location.href does not work to save the current web page url as a bookmark. Does anyone perhaps know why?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "save as a bookmark"? Can you elaborate and show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works in Firefox as well as IE.

```
function CreateBookmarkLink() {

 title = "Webpage Title"; 
 //or title = document.title

 url = "Webpage URL";
 //or url = location.href

if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
    window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url,"");
} else if( window.external ) { // IE Favorite
    window.external.AddFavorite( url, title); }

}
```

[Source](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html)

```
<a href="javascript:CreateBookmarkLink()" >Bookmark Page</a>
```

Comment: `sidebar.addPanel()` is no more standard hence with the newest versions for firefox it's now deprecated and might not work anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead...

```
javascript:window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);
```