# Web app in Android browser: prompt visitor to save bookmark?

Tags: android, web-applications, bookmarks, android-browser

I've written a webapp for iOS and android. On iOS, I've found [this](http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/) awesome tool to prompt iOS users to add a bookmark to their homescreen.

What are the options for doing something similar in android? I think that the re-skinning of browser apps done by different manufacturers is going to make it difficult to have a popup with instructions pointing at any specific area of the screen.

Is it possible to prompt a user to save a bookmark using javascript? I've considered the possibility of broadcasting an intent from the page that would do this, but I'm doubtful it's possible.

My last option would be to build a wrapper app that users could be prompted to download, but that seems excessive. Hoping not to go down this route if I don't have to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bookmark page using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064703/bookmark-page-using-javascript)